# My php form is sending the email but not the data

Tags: php

This is the portion of code that is giving me issues, it is sending email to my address but not the data completed in the form from the website:

```
        $emailSubject = 'Website Enquiry';
    $webMaster = 'cynthiab1984@gmail.com';

/*Gathering Data Variables*/

    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
    $commentField = $_POST['comment'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
name: $name<br>
email: $email<br>
phone number: $phone<br>
comment: $comment<br>

EOD;
    $headers = "From:$email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail ($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: please mark question with the green checkmark if it is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your fields are called `$nameField` etc, and you're putting them in the email body as `$name`

Comment: And I'm just sitting here wasting my life trying to verify if the `<<<EOD` was correct =) +1

Comment: I did! Sorry about that!

Comment: I feel like the other answerers just take joy in beating a dead horse lol

Comment: No problem - if this is correct, please mark it correct by clicking the tick (next to the voting buttons) so future readers will find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check you field names you will find the problem.
Fields should be:

```
$nameField 
  $emailField
  $phoneField 
 $commentField
```

not:

```
$name
$email
$phone
$comment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Edits made below
// This is your area to edit

$body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    name: $nameField<br>
    email: $emailField<br>
    phone number: $phoneField<br>
    comment: $commentField<br>
```