# PHP Data Variables Missing from email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Okay so I created the php file for my contact form, here is my php code *(I have removed my email)*:

```
<?php
/* Subject and Email Variables */ 


    $emailSubject = 'CV Website!';
    $email_to = '-----------';

/* Gathering Data Variables */


    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $messageField = $_POST['message'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Message: $message <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($email_to, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Here is the form it is connected to:

```
<form action="process.php" id="contact_form" method="post" class="wow
fadeInUpBig" data-wow-offset="80" data-wow-duration="2s">

    <p>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="requiredField name" />
    </p>

     <p>
       <label>Email Address</label>             
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""  class="requiredField email" /> 
     </p>

      <p>
        <label>Your Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" cols="30" class="requiredField message"></textarea>
      </p>

       <p> 
         <input name="submitted" id="submitted" value="Submit" class="submit" type="submit" />
       </p>
  </form>
```

When I test the form all I get through is a message like this:

> Name:
>
> Email:
>
> Message:

And no input data, please help if you see what iv'e done wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the method of your form?

Comment: Try turning on error reporting

Comment: First off, your PHP variables names do not match what you are setting as inputs to you email body.

Comment: Can you post the full form code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My php form is sending the email but not the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892359/my-php-form-is-sending-the-email-but-not-the-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start you should try this then make changes as you need to:

```
$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$messageField = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $nameField <br>
Email: $emailField <br>
Message: $messageField <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
$headers .="Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($email_to, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing you need this tag for your form:

```
<form method="post" ... >
      ... <!-- Input Fields go here -->
</form>
```